# Not detecting change in state when storing an array

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am storing an array in my store, but I my mapStateToProps is not detecting the change, and updating props.  Here is my Store:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = 
{   
    someArray:[]
};
```

and here is my mapStateToProps.

```
function mapStateToProps(state){
  return{
      someArray: state.publications.someArray
  }
}
```

If I add something to detect change in length, it does detect a change, but this is obviously not correct.  What am I doing wrong?

```
 function mapStateToProps(state){
      return{
          someArray: state.publications.someArray,
          detectChange: state.publications.someArray.length
      }
    }
```

Here is my root reducer:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    publications: PUBLICATIONS_REDUCER

});
```

and here is the reducer switch that is triggered:

```
case UPDATE_INDEX_HEADER_SORT_ARRAY:
    return {...state, someArray: action.payload}
```

where payload is the array.

Comment: How do you know that the state actually changed?

Answer (score 0):

Your reducer puts the payload directly into the state. The state should at all times be immutable. But the array that is in the state is also being referenced elsewhere. The code is not included, but I envision one of 2 options.

Option one is that you have some variable that hangs on to the array, modifies it to add or delete items and then dispatches an action to put that array in the state.

Option two is that some function reads the `publications` from the state, proceeds to push, pop or splice something on or off this array,  and then dispatches an action to put that array in the state.

In both cases you should realize a few things:

- The same array that is in the state is the one you are modifying after you store it in the state. It's just a reference, so by pushing, popping, splicing, or setting any item or property of any item, or property of a descendant anywhere in that array, you are mutating the state. The state should be immutable.
- When you go to put this array in an action and then, in the reducer, store it in the state, you are actually not doing anything. The array you're storing is already stored there. It's the same array.
- Both cases are essentially the same thing.

Redux doesn't look in your array to see if anything changes. To do so it would need to search the array, the items in the array, and all sub items and sub-sub items, all the way down. Redux would get exhausted from all that comparing. By mandating that the state be immutable, Redux has made it easy on itself. It can just [check if the array is the same object](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/components/connect.js#L165) [as before](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/components/connect.js#L246), because if it is then the whole tree must be the same. After all, if any property anywhere in the tree changed, then its parent must also have changed, all the way down to the root state. If you break the covenant with Redux and try to trick it by mutating and then storing this mutation with the help of an action, then Redux will not take kindly to that.

Also, taking your array and fidgeting with it outside of a reducer indicates that perhaps you're not quite grasping the reasoning behind a Redux. You're probably feeling that this action/reducer business is a bit over the top and you just want to push something, or set a deeply nested property. Then notifying Redux by sending it a token action just so Redux can feel it's included in the party.

Redux doesn't want to just string along as an afterthought. Having actions like SET_ENTIRE_STATE defeats the purpose and philosophy of Redux. You are encouraged to make many action types and many fine grained reducers. This empowers Redux and it will repay you in kind as it will gladly share its power with you. The best part: Redux is humble and it will let you take all the credit.

That said, it is understandable that you're jaded from having your beloved imperative style robbed from you by immutable mandate. This is why I wrote [Redux-Schema](https://github.com/ddsol/redux-schema). It allows you to use imperative style coding while still using the Redux Way everywhere.